Kafka proxy to filter messages
I need to write a proxy server for a kafka broker as a web application. Cannot use out of box load  balancers like NGINX as those incur costs on the cloud for license. Cannot use the cloud load balancers as well because the public access to the broker is restricted even from vpc. But I can use EC2 or VMs to host a proxy app and do filtering of messages before sending to kafka.  Basically we are trying to fit in 2 requirements :

Expose the kafka brokers directly through our own app using the binary TCP protocol itself(should NOT be a rest proxy, how to expose this ?). Can I use an Inbound Channel adapter from Spring Integration framework ?

Use Spring integration framework to do routing of messages to specific topics. Basically the client would send it to one topic (topicA). But depending on the content we have to divert it to topicB or topicC.  Is Spring integration a good framework to do both these above things, because I know its pretty good in routing and filtering.


Spring cloud-stream a fit ?

I'm not sure Spring offers anything that would allow you to expose a TCP server that matches the Kafka TCP client protocol (in other words, are you also wanting to write your own clients to send data to the proxy?)

No. @OneCricketeer We are not planning to write our own client. Just the application for accepting messages

Is it more like an HTTP proxy in front of Kafka? For example, instead of directly accessing the Kafka topic partitions, does the application talk to a REST-based proxy for producing and consuming records?  sort of like Confluent's kafka proxy? In Spring, you need to write custom code to make that happen. Both Spring Integration and Spring Cloud Stream can be used for that purpose, but at the moment, the application needs to add this proxy layer.

Your first option, I think, is completely outside the scope of Spring or any other framework for that matter - you need to interact with Kafka directly. All the support available in Spring is only via the Java clients.

Hi Sobychacko, by java clients you mean simple components right? I just need a pass-thorugh component. Cannot I have a "listener" embedded in my application which simply forwards the messages to kafka. A framework which accepts message fro internet and sends it to kafka inside private nw.

By Java client i mean the kafka java clients provided by Apache Kafka. All the support that Spring provides for Kafka makes use of the java client (as opposed to using Kafka wire protocol directly). Yes, you can have a listener as you suggest, but that is going to be a custom component at your application layer.

@sobychacko Quick question : I think you are one of the authors in Spring cloud stream. Can I use TcpSupplier and send the incoming data from the tcp port to Kafka broker ?

That is possible, but it depends on the use case - TCP supplier sources data from a TCP server, so this is a lower-level operation. We also have an HTTP supplier that can source data from HTTP endpoint.
